# MIPS CODE sum of n natural numbers (1 to n) WITHOUT USING BRANCH INSTRUCTION

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, mips, mips32

```
.data
input: .asciiz "Enter limit for the sum of natural number = "
show: .asciiz " \n sum of natural numbers are =   "

.text
main:
#get the integer input from user
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, input
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s5, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s5
    syscall
    
    addi $t5, $t5, 0
iteration:
    blt $t5, $s5, increment 
    j end
increment:  
    add $s2, $s2, $t5
    addi $t5, $t5, 1
j iteration
end:    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, show
    syscall  
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s2
    syscall
```

Ok, so I know how to take sum of n natural numbers by user input with Branch instruction but my question is: **"How do I execute that same program without using Branch instructions (bge, bltv bne etc.)"**

Comment: I think you have a typo, "execute" should be spelled "rewrite". ;-)

Comment: That would imply without using a loop.  The easiest way is to do the math using [the closed-form expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50485) `n * (n+1)/2` (or a modification of it that avoids overflow, if you want to be extra safe.)  MIPS has a multiply instruction, `mult`.  (Or the newer easier to use `mul`).

Comment: Depending on the range of your inputs you can prepare a lookup table containing the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a formula to compute something, as is the case with the specific problem statement in question, that's generally the best approach.

---

However, if you are looking more broadly for conditional execution without using classic conditional branch instructions, you can have it using unconditional branch through register instructions, with MIPS, the `jr <reg>`, jump register.

Background: the conditional branch instructions test a condition and either branch or fall through to the next instruction — that is to say, there is a choice of two destinations (for the subsequently executing instruction stream) that is made dynamically.

While a jump through register will always change the flow of control and never "fall through", by definition, a jump through register can set any number of different destinations, by computing one (of several) prior to that instruction.

The simple way to look at it is to compute the following:

```
    done := i < N
    whereToGo := (&doneLabel * done) + (&LoopTop * !done)
```

First, a boolean is computed, whose value is either 1 or 0.  In the above  `whereToGo` computation, only one of the two terms will be non-zero, using multiplicative identity, 1, in one case and the null factor, 0, in the other case.

(Let's note that in MIPS the `<` operation to form a boolean is done with `slt` and similar, and in particular, without use of conditional branch instructions.)

Here's a larger example, using a loop:

```
    ... // loop initialization
loopTop:
    <do something>
    done := i < N
    <reg> := (&doneLabel * done) + (&LoopTop * !done)
    jr <reg>
 doneLabel:
    ...
```

---

For those who wish to avoid multiplication to accomplish this, we can use the `AND` instead.  To use an `AND` operation, we need not a boolean 1 vs. 0, but an altered boolean -1 vs. 0.  For `AND`, -1 is the identity and 0 is the null factor.

```
    done := i < N             // produces 1 or 0 result (for true, false, resp.)
    mask := done - 1          // produces 0 or -1 result
    whereToGo := (&doneLabel & ~mask) | (&LoopTop & notDone)
```

In the above, `mask` will be will be 0 when `done` is true (and we want to exit, so we use `~mask` on that term), while it will be -1 when done is false.

Since one term will always be 0, then addition, `+` vs. OR, `|` are equivalent.

---

This approach can be generalized with more terms to choose between more destinations, of course, as long as only one term's boolean evaluates to identity and all the others are null.

Comment: Most people would consider an indirect jump to be a branch.  It needs branch-prediction, after all.  (But so do direct jumps, so that's not definitive.)  More importantly, it has multiple possible destinations, and using it this way it would actually go to different destinations.  So whether this is allowed or not depends on the exact wording.  "No branching" vs. "no using any `b..` instructions".

Comment: MIPS IV and later have `movz` and `movn` conditional-move instruction, which can optimize the `(&label1 & mask) | (&label2 & ~mask)` selection down to 1 instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes, in MIPS speak, `branches` are typically conditional and `jumps` are typically unconditional.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of 1..n equals (n*(n+1))/2

In pseudocode:

```
temp := (input + 1)
temp := (temp * input)
result := (temp >> 1)
```

Comment: The middle +1 step is useless.  `n * (n+1)` is always an even number because either `n` or `n+1` will be even.  You're just setting the LSB=1 for the shift to discard.  There's no rounding needed in this formula; it's exact.  ([Sum of  n consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50514))

Comment: (It can overflow in cases where the sum loop wouldn't have, though.  When clang optimizes a loop into this, it uses a variation that avoids overflow, doing a widening multiply and shifting some bits from the high half: https://godbolt.org/z/K58G5rhWo)

Comment: The classic [binary search overflow bug](https://thebittheories.com/the-curious-case-of-binary-search-the-famous-bug-that-remained-undetected-for-20-years-973e89fc212?gi=6e4fcd4c624) in certain cases of large numbers where the proper answer would have still fit within range.

Comment: @PeterCordes, "either n or n+1 must be even" good point, thanks!